# Election Query -yet another issue. Major

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

This Query was bringing me the results like I wanted. And thats great!

```
select  rc.[race number],
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then winner end) as WinnerSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then winner end) as LoserSelected

from 
(
select  rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],
            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number]          
) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

Problem I am having now is that there is a title1 field in the RACE table that I need to have in the query. I am unable to bind that multipart identifier. This is what started my whole seek and destroy on the forum.

Each race has a title and 2 candidates. I was trying to put both candidates, and the leading data into one single rowset. Now, the only thing I am missing is the title1 field! AHhhh! it never ends.

I don't think I can have it within the max(case select, because it would definitely duplicate the race number.

I hope this makes sense. I am sorry for wasting so much bandwidth on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  rc.[race number] AS RaceNumber,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then title1 end) as title1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as WinnerSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as LoserSelected


from 
(
select  
        r.title1,
        rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],

            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number] 

) rc
group by rc.[race number]
```

I got it. Thanks Everyone!!!